# Express gives the same response even with different input-values in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new learning Express and MongoDB. I'm following an Udemy course, and I'm sure that my code is exactly the same.

**My problem:**

When I post some data to a MongoDB collection, it works as expected. But when I try to add a new value, it works, but inserts the same value that the first post, even when the inputs values are differents.

Here is some of my code:

#### pacienteControllers.js

```
const Paciente = require('../models/Paciente');

exports.newClient = async (request, response, next) =>{
   const paciente = new Paciente(request.body);
   try {
      await paciente.save();
      response.json({mensaje: 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'});
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      next();
   }
}
```

#### routes/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const PacienteController = require('../controllers/PacienteControllers');

module.exports = () =>{

   router.get('/', () =>{
      console.log("Petición enviada");
   })

   router.post('/pacientes',
      PacienteController.newClient
   )

   return router;
}
```

#### index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const server = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://AlexisDominguez:11399102a@my-free-cluster-ojd2d.mongodb.net/veterinaria?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useFindAndModify: false 
});

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

server.use('/', routes());

server.listen(4000, () => console.log("servidor funcionando"));
```

Note: *username* and *password* are correct values, just censured for security reasons.

I would like to know why is this happening. ¿Is there some kind of cache?

**TESTS**

I'm using Postman to do posts tests. When I do the first post I get the message: `El cliente se agregó correctamente` meaning that the client was added successfuly.

But when I try to add a new register to the database, I get the same message but, when I update the database to see new changes, I get the new register but with the same values of the first post.

**EDIT**

Added `server.use(bodyParser.json());` but still getting same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only import routes folder but not `index.js` file in your root file  `index.js` so import as

```
const routes = require('./routes/index');
```

You are sending message in `JSON` object But you didn;t use `middleware` in `index.js` so add

```
server.use(bodyParser.JSON());
```

Your `routes` and `controller` can be merged like this: In your `routes/index.js` file add this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Paciente = require('../models/Paciente');

router.post('/pacientes', async (req, res) => {
  const paciente = new Paciente(req.body);
  try {
     const saveData = await paciente.save();
     res.json({ message: "El cliente se agregó correctamente" });
     }
       catch ( err ) {
         res.json({ message: err }); 
       }
     });

 //You can view all the data from here
   router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    const data  = await Paciente.find();
     try {
       res.json(data);
     }  catch( err ) {
         res.json({ message: err })
        }
     });
 module.exports = router;
```

You can now remove `pacienteController.js` file

Comment: I did the first step correctly and added `server.use(bodyParser.json())` before `server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))` line but I get the same results.

Comment: If I try the new code I get the following error: `/home/alexisarieldominguezsanchez/Documentos/Programación/Curso de Javascript Moderno/API con Express-Node-MongoDB-React-Electron/API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139
  debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at Function.handle (/home/alexisarieldominguezsanchez/Documentos/Programación/Curso de Javascript Moderno/API con Express-Node-MongoDB-React-Electron/API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:34)`

Comment: Do you have your code on github ? You can share me your github's link

Comment: Sorry for waiting, I was having problems with github. Here is the repository: https://github.com/AlexisDominguez/Veterinaria.git

Comment: Problem solved https://github.com/kedarSedai/StackOverflow  add your `username` and `password` to the `database/keys.js` file  and in your `postman` use `POST` method in order to save data in  database use URL as `http://localhost:3000/posts/pacientes` and in `GET` method use URL as `http://localhost:3000/posts`